# Random number in different language

Tags: javascript, matlab, random

I have two codes which have the same algorithm but implemented in different programming languages, MATLAB and JavaScript. In my implementation, I use betarnd, rand and randn in MATLAB and use jStat.beta.sample, jStat.uniform.sample and jStat.rand to generate random number in both codes (each jStat random function has conforming to definition of each MATLAB function).

JavaScript:

```
yxt = 1000 + parseFloat(jStat.rand(1));
```

MATLAB:

```
yxt = 1000 + randn;
```

I found the results of the same algorithm with such random number are quite different. So I wonder that is it possible getting random numbers in various stochasticity in different programming languages?

Comment: Long story short: Yes, they vary between different programming languages.  Each language may use different algorithms as random numbers are essentially produced by a pseudorandom generator.  This generator varies between topologies, methodologies and architectures.  See the duplicate link for a more detailed discussion.